# how to access one by on value of the stored procedure and calculate the average of them row wise

Tags: average

I executed a stored procedure in java which results into a table of 16 column and 3600 rows.Now I want to access 3 column of the retrieved table in row by row fashion and calculate the average of all column in row wise fashion.To do this,I need to access values of columns one by one .How to do it. My code for accessing column is

```js
while (rs.next())
     {
      a1=rs.getDouble(7);
      a2=rs.getDouble(8);
      a3=rs.getDouble(10);
       sum +=(a1+a2+a3);
    
     }
 return sum/3;
```

but through this,i think i'am getting a total average of all the columns .But i need average of column row by row i.e average of all three column of first row,then second row ...like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed adding all the values from 3 columns and doing row by row addition.

If you want row by row, then for each entry that you get from database you need to store the result in a list like below and return it where needed:

```
List<Double> averageList = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (rs.next())
{
    a1=rs.getDouble(7);
    a2=rs.getDouble(8);
    a3=rs.getDouble(10);
    averageList.add((a1+a2+a3)/3.0);
}
return averageList;
```

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver.But now i have to store these values into the averge_pressure column of the table which is empty right now.how to do it.Right now these values are displayed in a random fashion.

Comment: so instead of List use map which will have map with id as key (primary key) and value as average. This is follow up question so you should close this one and start a new one.

Comment: I can post only once in every 90 minutes.So will you please tell me how to use map for my qusetion.

Comment: Map<Integer, Double> averageMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(); and in while loop you could do like averageMap.put(rs.getInt(1), (a1+a2+a3)/3.0);//where 1st column i assume is id or something that's unique

Comment: thanx again.How to store these in a table format in jsp page.

Comment: :) you really need to raise as a separate question now.